# How to change font in upTex/upLaTeX

Tags: fonts, japanese, uplatex, ptex

I'm using uplatex to write some Japanese articles. I want to change font for the text, but I don't know how.

Unlike xelatex which I've used for most of the time, `\usepackage{fontspec}` won't compile in uplatex.

How do I change font to, say, `Noto Serif CJK JP` or `SimSun`?

I use `uplatex + dvipdfmx` to compile. I have TexLive2021 installed on Windows.

A MWE is provided below:

```
% Compile with upLaTeX + dvipdfmx
% ----------------------------------------------------
\documentclass[12pt]{ujarticle}
\begin{document}
\section*{紀伊国牟婁郡悪女}
有二沙門。一人年若。其形端正。一人年老。共詣熊野。至牟婁郡。宿路辺宅。其宅主寡婦。出両三女従者。宿居二僧。致志労養。爰家女夜半至若僧辺。覆衣並語僧言。我家従昔不宿他人。今夜借宿。非無所由。従見始時。有交臥之志。仍所令宿也。為遂其本意所進来也。僧大驚怪。起居語女言。日来精進。出立遥途。参向権現宝前。如何有此悪事哉。更不承引。女大恨怨。通夜抱僧。擾乱戯咲。僧以種々詞語誘。参詣熊野。只両三日。献燈明御幣。還向之次。可随君情。作約束了。僅遁此事。参詣熊野。
\end{document}
```

Output with default font (I don't even know what font it is):
[image]

Comment: Here is a post (in Chinese) that maybe helpful: https://www.zhihu.com/question/20544732/answer/15437234 p.s. Clerk Ma is a contributor to XeTeX as well as pTeX. And also this blog: https://zhuanlan.zhihu.com/p/81728243

Comment: Here is a blog post in Japanese about switching to Source Han Serif (aka Noto Serif CJK JP): https://qiita.com/zr_tex8r/items/9dfeafecca2d091abd02

Comment: @RuixiZhang Thank you so much! I'll check it out. It just seems to be much more complicated than using xelatex. (Xiexie xiongdi)